# Common messenger app for phone and PC

Tags: instant-messaging

Is there a way to do messaging on my PC and my Android? In other words, using either has the same contacts and you can see the same messages in both places?

Comment: Please note: Asking for an app that does something is off-topic here, largely because it's simply a popularity contest with short, uninformative answers with people listing their favorite app of that type. It's much better to describe the problem you're trying to solve. I've edited your question to be more along those lines. Please also see: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289)

Answer (score 2):

[Google Hangouts](http://www.google.com/hangouts/). Does text chat, video chat, and can even send and receive SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/) does that. It is a valide alternative to WhatsApp, the account(and contacts) are shared among every device you use. It also has some Unofficial Windows/Linux/Mac OSX clients.

Answer (score 0):

Line is a great messenger that works for PC and Phone. It is also the second most populated app, I believe, about 100 million less users than WeChat.

http://line.me/en/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Whatsapp messenger on PC using Blue Stacks, Windroy, Youwave android etc.

Answer (score 0):

MightyText is app that does what you asked for. And it's pretty popular, too!
I personally did not try it yet, but it was recommended to me several times.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms